# Using Python in Netbeans

Tags: python, netbeans

I have x64 Windows XP machine.

I use Netbeans to code Java.

I am now trying to use it for Python, but I get this error:

\NetBeans was unexpected at this time.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to ask this question on www.serverfault.com rather than stackoverflow as it is more of a configuration issue rather than a programming issue.

Include the version of Netbeans and the Java you are using - and whether you using native python and/or Jython as well.

Also include at which point you see the error message - when you create a new file, new project etc - does Netbeans start up ok etc ?